# Unity: skinned mesh vertexbuffer output slightly different than correct results

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, vertex-buffer

It’s like this hip is stuck in place, with in the pictures(being at different times in the animation since I can’t upload a gif) the red wireframe is the drawing of the raw output triangles and everything else being default unity, aka the correct output
What am I doing wrong? What am I missing? This has been driving me nuts for 2-3 days now, any help is appreciated

[image: Red is raw output from vertex buffer, everything else is default unity]

[image: different frame of the animation showing the offset or difference is not constant]

Answer (score 0):

As you do not post any code, I will try to do some guessing over what is going on. Disclamair: I actually happen to run into similar problem myself.

First, you must know that Update's of MonoBehaviour are called in random order (not neccessery random-random, but yous see the point). If you bake mesh in one component, it can still be one-frame late to the Animator component.

There are actually two solution of this case: first is to specify the order of Script Execution Order in Project Settings, while the second is to use `LateUpdate` instead of `Update` when updating mesh after skinning.

The second problem you might have run into is scale / position of skinned mesh. **Even if it does not contribute at all to the animation movement** it can still wreck the mesh baking collision later on.

To fix that make sure that all your `SkinnedMeshRenderers` objects have Local Position, Local Rotation and Local Scale set in Transform component to identity (0,0,0 for position and rotation, 1,1,1 for scale). If not - reset those values in editor. It will not change animations, but it will change mesh generator.

If both solutions does not work, please describe the problem more thoroughly.